# Displaying data from an API with React

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I am trying to display data from the https://newsapi.org/ API using map and I get this error:
"articles.map is not a function".

I am able to display data in the same program from another API with no problem. I think it has to do with the JSON I get from the API. Every object in the JSON I get back from the API which I am able to display has a unique ID property which I can use in my props key. This ID has been set up explicitly for that purpose. Objects in the newsapi have no property like an ID. There are properties in the JSON which have unique values though and could be used to serve that function, so I don't think maybe there is some other underlying issue with the JSON. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

below is the JSON that I can display.

```
[
  {
    "id": "rec6d6T3q5EBIdCfD",
    "name": "Best of Paris in 7 Days Tour",
    "info": "Paris is synonymous with the finest things that culture can offer — in art, fashion, food, literature, and ideas. On this tour, your Paris-savvy Rick Steves guide will immerse you in the very best of the City of Light: the masterpiece-packed Louvre and Orsay museums, resilient Notre-Dame Cathedral, exquisite Sainte-Chapelle, and extravagant Palace of Versailles. You'll also enjoy guided neighborhood walks through the city's historic heart as well as quieter moments to slow down and savor the city's intimate cafés, colorful markets, and joie de vivre. Join us for the Best of Paris in 7 Days!",
    "image": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/a0cd0702c443f31526267f38ea5314a1/2447eb7a/paris.jpg",
    "price": "1,995"
  },
  {
```

.
.
.

below is the JSON from newsapi which I cannot display

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 38,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "CBS Sports"
      },
      "author": "Brian Campbell",
      "title": "Errol Spence Jr. vs. Danny Garcia fight results: Live boxing updates, scorecard, start time, undercard - CBSSports.com",
      "description": "Follow live as a pair of welterweight titles are on the line in Arlington, Texas",
      "url": "https://www.cbssports.com/boxing/news/errol-spence-jr-vs-danny-garcia-fight-results-live-boxing-updates-scorecard-start-time-undercard/live/",
      "urlToImage": "https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2019/09/26/2582e7ad-d4e3-4845-86ac-8996ab597932/thumbnail/1200x675/5325daca4acf1cd4f34fd5bf64003992/errol-spence-jr.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2020-12-06T04:27:00Z",
      "content": "Welterweight supremacy is on the line on Saturday night in Arlington, Texas, when unified champion Errol Spence Jr. takes on Danny Garcia in the main event of a Fox PPV. It will be Spence's (26-0, 21… [+1770 chars]"
    },
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"articles.map is not a function". means that articles need to be an array. You can only map over an array in Javascript.

and indeed, first JSON (when parsed) is an array. It starts with [ and ends with ]. Inside of this array, there is one or more objects.

Second JSON is just an object. You are receiving object from the api, as they are adding some more information such as status and totalResults.
You can use status property to know the status of the response, and totalResults for pagination purposes, for example.
Then they give you the array of articles you are looking for.

You can only map via this array.

So assuming you store the result of the api call in variable data, your map function would look like: data.articles.map((element) => {... do something with element ... })

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I am pretty new to programming, so it is nice to have a clear explanation about the object versus the array and I think that is near the root of the problem. I store the data from the newsapi call in a variable I have named data (just by coincidence I guess).  I set up the map function the way you have suggested, but now I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" which I have gotten before.

Comment: If you get this error that means that data.articles is undefined. Do you ruj map on data.articles? Console log data and find out what you received from api. Also make sure data is not string, but object. If it is string, use JSON.parse() to convert it from string to object.

Comment: I run map on data.articles. the data variable just contains the JSON I get back from the API call. I log the data and get this

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I think maybe I am just having a hard time finding the right entry point get the data I want from the response. I'm going to try a little more to figure it out. I put some of the src files on GitHub if you are curious https://github.com/jonathanHandwerk/React-Articles